# S3 folder structure for hive partitioned tables without "=" in it

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, emr

I have an existing S3 folder structure like this,

```
s3://mydata/{country}/{date}/
```

- `{country}` could be any of 30 different countries
- `{date}` could be any date since 20150101

How can I read this in Hive by treating {country} as partition and {date} as sub partition ?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this? I am also curious.

Comment: Hive needs '=' to automatically understand partitions. Only way this can be achieved is to create table separately pointing to the parent path and do 'add partitions' with specific path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hive DDL statement `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION`

```
ALTER TABLE mydata
ADD PARTITION (country='south-africa', date='20191024')
LOCATION 's3://mydata/south-africa/20191024/';
```

You can script this using a shell script, and passing each statement to Hive like `hive -e 'ALTER TABLE $TABLE ADD PARTITION $PARTITION_SPEC LOCATION $PARTITION_LOCATION'`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions